# Is there a Kdenlive PPA for Ubuntu trusty or how to use a PPA for a different version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, ppa, kdenlive

The official PPAs do not offer packages for trusty. Can I still use them to install for example the packages for utopic at my own risk? Or is there a PPA with packages for trusty? And no, I can not upgrade to utopic right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the link, [Kdenlive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdenlive&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) is available via the default Ubuntu 14.04 repository.  If you are having problems with the default installation, you might consider posting a description of the problem which might be resolved by some workaround with some of the codecs or other system libraries and utilities that are part of Trusty.

A ppa provided for an earlier version might be more compatible than a ppa provided for a later OS version, because newer OS' often comes with upgraded components (libraries and functions) that might not be totally compatible with a previous version of Ubuntu.  Trying to update each library with to make your installation compatible to a later OS might take more work that you would anticipate than just upgrading to the later OS, which you have already specified that you are not ready to do.

You can, alternatively, review the daily built page that includes very up-to-date links to kdenlive tarballs:
[Kdenlive Daily Builds](https://kdenlive.org/aggregator/sources/7)

When installing packages from tarball you usually have a choice of alternate location install, which allows you to either run your daily built install (which might have some glitches) or the official release, separately.

The packages I install from tarball or from compiled source, I install in a subdirectory of `/opt`.

---

As mentioned above, I'm certain that you'd experience more work trying to fix incompatible libraries and modules using a later ppa than you would have in upgrading your OS where you would have full support for your OS by upgrading.

Just looking at the fact that they don't maintain the current 14.04 LTS in their ppa support makes it appear there might be compatible issues that they are not prepared to deal with.  I'm sure it would be ideal to have automatic updates, but the only automatic updates they are providing (as you see) is the ones provided in the repository.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to use a ppa because the one in the ubuntu repo is several years old.

Comment: I want to use the same version that I use on my utopic PC, if possible. I could probably build it from source, but that quite a hassle as opposed to getting the updates from a ppa

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Your reasoning is fully understandable.  I provided a formatted detailed explanation in an addendum to my answer.